# How to select date between start and end with varchar datatype?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Table_name');
$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE("$start", "%Y-%m-%d") and STR_TO_DATE("$ends", "%Y-%m-%d")');
```

This is my query but it's not working. I'm working in CodeIgniter framework

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are using single quotes in query string, this means your variables `$start` `$ends` have not interpolated

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') between STR_TO_DATE('$start', '%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE('$ends', '%Y-%m-%d') This is my query, it's work fine in mysq and core phpl. I want to convert this query in codeigniter format.

Comment: Neither the code in your question nor the one in the last comment is a valid SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work form me.

```
     $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
     $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ends));
     $this->db->where('_date >=',  $start_date);
     $this->db->where('_date <=',  $end_date);
     $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2018-01-01')); //enter date according to your requirements 
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table-name WHERE date BETWEEN '$end_date' AND '$start_date'");
return $query_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **datepicker** to take input. It will be easier for you.
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

This should work for you. **_date** is the column name

```
$this->db->where('_date >=', STR_TO_DATE($start, '%Y-%m-%d'));
$this->db->where('_date <=', STR_TO_DATE($ends, '%Y-%m-%d'));
print_r($this->db->get('Table_name'));
```

Comment: Call to undefined function STR_TO_DATE()

Comment: If you convert $start_date and $end_date like this 
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ends));

Then use
$this->db->where('_date >=',  $start_date);
     $this->db->where('_date <=',  $end_date);
     $query = $this->db->get('table_name');